# GCC 5.1 library dependencies on old distributions - walkthough

Tags: c++, g++, gcc5

I compiled and install GCC 5.1.0 on my CentOS 5.11 (with default GCC 4.x onboard).

It is safe to run  compiled (on this machine) binary on another CenOS 5.11  workstation, where is no any gcc 5.1 runtime libraries (/usr/local/lib64) ?

Will be gratefull to any suggestions .

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only it is unsafe, it is likely impossible. You have a good chance of having a runtime-library incompatibility and missing proper GLIB defined symbol - which will trigger run-time dynamic linker errors. But this is if you are lucky. If you are unlucky, your program might run, but crash. Or not crash in the given form, but start crashing once you call a function on iostream.

Unfortunately, libstdc++ is not so-versioned, so automatic so version verification will not help you.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So then my  next question - can I deploy libstdc++.so  with my binary ? somewhere in /usr/local/mylib64 with correspond rpath linking, Thank you.

Comment: @user1503944, sure you can.

Comment: _"libstdc++ is not so-versioned"_, huh?